# Не могу решить задачу, проверка выводит Wrong Answer. Условие приложил

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Условие задачи!]
[http://contester.alexandrov.ru/ru/problem-pid-c59f?ps=1&smt=7&smpwid=0]

Известна информация о результатах N спортсменов, участвовавших в соревнованиях по бегу на 100 м (все числа разные, вещественные, вводятся с клавиатуры). Определить результаты спортсменов, занявших первое, второе и третье места.

Входные данные:

В первой строке целое число N (не более 100). Во второй строке результаты спортсменов (вещественные числа, не превышающие 100) через пробел.

Выходные данные:

Выведите три числа в одной строке: результаты спортсменов, занявших первое, второе и третье места, соответственно.

```
from collections import Counter
import sys
k = 0
b = 0
n = int(input())
if n <= 100 and n >= 0 :
    a = list(map(float, input().split()))[:n]
    counter = Counter(a)
    if sum(counter) == sum(a):
        a = sorted(a)
    else:
        sys.exit()
for i in range(len(a)):
    b = a[k]
    if 0 <= b <= 100:
        k += 1
    else:
        sys.exit()
if a[0] - int(a[0]) == 0:
    a[0] = int(a[0])
else:
    a[0] = float(a[0])
if a[1] - int(a[1]) == 0:
    a[1] = int(a[1])
else:
    a[1] = float(a[1])
if a[2] - int(a[2]) == 0:
    a[2] = int(a[2])
else:
    a[0] = float(a[0])
print(a[0],a[1],a[2])
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос условия задачи - текстом, а не картинкой. Вы хоть опишите свой алгоритм. зачем у вас в коде counter и, тем более, sys?

Comment: @strawdog , С помощью sum(counter) я узнавал, нет ли в строке (a) повторений, а с помощью sys.exit прекращал выполнение программы, если условие не выполнялось

Comment: у вас в условии нигде не сказано про повторения. и sys.exit здесь вообще не в тему. Зачем проверять ввод на условие 0 < n < 100, если таковы исходные параметры? у вас вообще решение должно сводиться к одной строке: `a = sorted(input().split()))[:3]` или, если уж важны числа: `a = sorted(map(int,input().split())))[:3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
try:
    results = map(float, input().split())
    print(*sorted(results)[:3])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Wrong Answer, к сожалению [http://contester.alexandrov.ru/ru/problem-pid-c59f?ps=1&smt=7&smpwid=0]

Comment: @NikitaPolyakov ну так поменяйте float на int, например.